# Multi-Site using Organic Groups

Tags: organic-groups, multi-sites

I am building a Drupal Multi-site.  The look and feel of all of the Multi-sites will be identical it is just the Data that will be different.  Within a site I need to restrict access to various areas so that one  user with the role of "authenticated user" can be restricted to only certain areas of the site, while another user with the same role can be restricted to a different area of the site.  Organic groups seems to be what I am looking for.

My question is, is there any reason that Organic Groups can not work with in a multi-site framework?